# Update SQL entry from TOP 1 by 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a inventory table that is:

```
Warehouse item vendor quantity expiration_date
US0001    i1   v1     20       2017-07-06
US0001    i1   v2     35       2017-12-12
US0001    i1   v3     10       2017-12-12
```

I need to follow the following policy to take out items:

1. Take the items with earliest expiration date first.
2. Take the items with smallest quantity if expiration date is the same.

If I take out 60 item i1, So I would subtract row1 with 20 first, and then subtract row3 with 10, then subtract 20 from row2. And then delete the 0 entries.

The updated table will look like:

```
Warehouse item vendor quantity expiration_date
US0001    i1   v2     15       2017-12-12
```

I wonder how can we do this as SQL query?

Plus. I'm doing this on a website. so php can also be a tool to help..

Thank you!

Comment: not possible with a single query. you'd have to do this iteratively, using multiple queries.

Comment: we can select those in those orders using order by. But how can we update in this sequence?

Comment: start a transaction, select those records with a `for update` lock, then start fetching rows and updating them with your new counts. once you're done. you commit() and go on.

Comment: is this sql-server?

Comment: Perhaps a stored procedure is the way to go

Comment: mysql can do that alone

Comment: Can anyone give me some example links or post an answer for me to start with?